# Errors installing the Curl library with PHP/Apache/Windows

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, php, curl

I'm having a hell of a time getting Curl to work with PHP/Apache on my Windows XP 64-bit development box. I have PHP and Apache successfully installed, but when I tried to enable Curl I get the following error (twice) from PHP on Apache startup:

```
"PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1."
```

I did uncomment the correct line in PHP.ini. I did move the two DLLs (php_curl.dll and ssleay32.dll) into my PHO root, into my System32, even my apache root - but no matter where I put them, PHP can't find them. I keep getting the error above. Anyone have any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

You said you put them in the root of your php directory, what about in c:\php\ext like the error message says? What are the permissions on the files?

Comment: The files have been in there since I installed PHP, and everything is writable. I installed MySQL with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Open php.ini and look to what `extension_dir` directive point to.